# The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type error when sort array by date

Tags: typescript

It sorts my board by date. However, I have a small problem with typescript. The code works as correctly as possible, but typescipt throws me an error

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

Full code

```
const chartArray = [];

for (let i of Object.keys(data.data.podcasts.data[0].attributes.podcast_popularities.data)) {
        chartArray.push(data.data.products.data[0].attributes.products.data[i].attributes);
        chartArray.sort((a, b): any => {
            return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
        });
}
```

The problem appears in this passage

```
chartArray.sort((a, b): any => {
            return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
});
```

How can I solve this type of problem? Is some type or something like that missing somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting dates only works because native dates objects already have a `valueOf` method. This method is implicitly called when converting operands.

TypeScript doesn't like this, and you aren't guaranteed that the operands haven't been tampered with (changing the `valueOf` method, for example).

You *could* solve it by calling `valueOf` yourself on each of the dates, but you should use the built-in `getTime` method:

```
return new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime();
```

[`getTime` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)